# Cleaning up CSS files

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a bunch of CSS files with a bunch of classes. I know a lot are not used.

Is there a tool that will scan your site and clean up your CSS files or tell me which ones aren't used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at excellent firefox addon:

**[Dust-Me Selectors](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017124244/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392/)**

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/img/uploads/previews/thumbs/23/23822.png?modified=1217228167))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

This site has some nice tricks about what you need to do [http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/useful-tools-to-check-clean-and-optimize-your-css-file/](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/useful-tools-to-check-clean-and-optimize-your-css-file/).

It suggests some tools like a Firefox plugin called **Dust-Me selectors**.. [http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130915072238/http://www.sitepoint.com:80/dustmeselectors/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/dustmeselector.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of different tools you're asking.

Firebug has a plugin called "CSS usage": it tells you what CSS files are used.

Then there's the [CSS minifier](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/) (compresses your CSS code).

And finally, there's the [CSS beautifier](http://www.codebeautifier.com/).

Comment: CSS Usage: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/ Its website (the one on spagetticoder) no longer exists. I keep getting "Storage not yet available" so I won't go as far as recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use [Dust-me selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/) and [CSS tidy](http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/).